Understanding the partition function for one particle
It might be an odd question but I'll try to put it well enough. We went in class through an example of a gas of $N$ molecules of mass $m$ contained in a box of horizontal section $A$ and height $L$. That gas is in a gravitational field of uniform acceleration $g$ and in equilibrium at temperature $T$.
We went on to find the average height $<z_i>$ of one molecule inside the box. And to do so, the teacher found the partition function for one molecule $z(N=1)$ and then used $Z(N)=\frac{z^N}{N!}$ to find the general one (system of $N$ molecules). But what confused me is that to find the average height of one molecule, he used the general one:
$$<z_i>=\frac{\int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec r_i d\vec p_i z_i e^{-\beta H}}{h^{3N}Z(N)}$$
With $H=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i^2}{2m}+mgz+\Phi_V(\vec r_i)$ being the hamiltonian and $\Phi_V(\vec r_i)=\begin{cases} 
0 \text{ if } \vec r_i \text{ inside the box}\\
\infty \text{ if } \vec r_i \text{ outside the box}
\end{cases}$ the potential energy of a molecule inside the box.
My question. If he is trying to find the average height of one molecule I don't get it why they use $Z(N)$ instead of $z(1)$. I've encountered yesterday a very very similar problem where it asked another average variable of one molecule and it indeed used $z(1)$, if needed I can post that other problem but it just shocked me that one used $Z(N)$ and the other $z(1)$, how can I know when to use which?

By $Z(N) = z^{N}/N!$, it looks like you have identical/indistinguishable particles.  When to use which obviously depends on whether the particles are distinguishable.
